# Enumerator and function scopes

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

Why an `Enumerator` does not keep track of the item in the same function but not if the `MoveNext`  operation happens in other function ?

Example:

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var array = new List<Int32>(new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        var e = array.GetEnumerator();
        e.MoveNext();
        e.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Current); // 2
        Incremenet(e);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Current); //2
    }

    static void Incremenet(IEnumerator<Int32> e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside " + e.Current); //2
        e.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside " + e.Current); // 3
        e.MoveNext();
        Console.WriteLine("Inside " + e.Current); //4
    }
```

I was expecting to get 5 in the last CW, but I get 2, like it was never incremented. Why the `MoveNext` inside the `Increment` function are forgotten when the function returns?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)'s enumerator type [`List<T>.Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s.aspx) is not a `class`, but a `struct`. Since [`GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765.aspx) exposes that the return type is `List<T>.Enumerator`, when you use `var`, `e`'s type is `List<T>.Enumerator`, so when you pass it to `Incremenet`, it is automatically [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) to be an `IEnumerator<Int32>` object. This is the cause of the strange behavior you're seeing.

If you type `e` as an `IEnumerator<Int32>`, the boxing happens as soon as you get the object, so this strange behavior does not happen: it works the same whether you run the other code in `Test` or in `Increment` (I fixed the spelling on that method, by the way, it's not "Incremenet").

```
public static void Test()
{
    var array = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    IEnumerator<Int32> e = array.GetEnumerator(); // boxed here
    e.MoveNext();
    e.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current); // 2
    Increment(e);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current); // now it's 4
}

static void Increment(IEnumerator<Int32> e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside " + e.Current); // 2
    e.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine("Inside " + e.Current); // 3
    e.MoveNext();
    Console.WriteLine("Inside " + e.Current); // 4
}
```

It is exposed as its type instead of `IEnumerator<T>` for performance reasons. `foreach` [is smart enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751967/why-is-listt-enumerator-faster-than-my-implementation) to call `MoveNext` and `Current` without boxing or virtual dispatch in such a case, and handles value type semantics without a problem. It does cause confusion, as you've seen, when you don't take great care of how you handle it though, since [mutable `struct`s are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Comment: They had to expose it externally though.  If they didn't expose it externally then it would *always* be boxed, and if it's always boxed, it may as well have just been a class to begin with.  The intent was that it would virtually always be used by a `foreach`, which would work correctly with value type semantics.  If the struct wasn't exposed publicly then the `foreach` couldn't pull out the enumerator without boxing it.  (At least without special compiler support, such as was done for arrays.)

Comment: @Servy Good point, good info, I've changed my answer in that portion.

Comment: @Servy I'm still not clear why it was made a `struct` instead of a `class` with `sealed`/non-`virtual` stuff in it. That would let you generate near-identical IL, that I think would have similar performance.

Comment: I know Eric Lippert stated that extensive testing was done and the struct performed significantly better in "standard" usages, and by enough to warrant making the change.

Comment: I noticed you edited the *exact* [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751967/why-is-listt-enumerator-faster-than-my-implementation) I was thinking of when I wrote my first comment.  Now I'm not so concerned that I wasn't able to find it quickly and so didn't post a link.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason `test` is 1 after increment in the following test case.  This is normal behavior for a value type.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int test = 1;
        Increment(test);
        Console.WriteLine("After increment: " + test);
    }

    static void Increment(int test)//add ref and the original variable will also update
    {
        test += 1;
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
```

As Servy pointed out technically, the example does differ in that the local variable `test` is immutable.  In reality the behavior we see is because the variable is copied to the `Increment` method.  However, my point is that this type of behavior is consistent across value types (both properties and local variables).  For further evidence of this fact:

```
struct MutableStruct
{
    public int EvilInt { get; set; }    
}

class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testStruct = new MutableStruct();
        testStruct.EvilInt = 1;

        int test = 1;
        Increment(test, testStruct);
        Console.WriteLine("After increment: " + test + " and..." + testStruct.EvilInt);//both 1
    }

    static void Increment(int test, MutableStruct test2)
    {
        test2.EvilInt += 1;
        test += 1;
        Console.WriteLine(test + " and..." + test2.EvilInt);//both 2
    }
}
```

As we can see here this behavior is normal across value types.  In both the case of local immutable value types and mutable structs the behavior remains consistent.

Comment: That's not true: your test fails because you're assigning a new value to `test`, which was passed by value. That's not what he's doing with his enumerator.

Comment: @dcastro The details of why structs do what they do are an exercise better left to someone studying the C# spec.  The scope and evil mutability of a value type is what I consider to be relevant here.

Comment: But that's just it.  Your example is demonstrating the semantics of an *immutable* value type.  The list enumerator is a *mutable* value type.  This answer doesn't even mention that.

Comment: @Servy - Fair enough.  I clarified the answer.